# Database for storing structures like Mind Map

Tags: database, data-structures, multimap, nosql

Good day!

I need to find a base for storage and processing complex structured information. 
Something like a mind map. Need to have some arbitrary values ​​in groups with connections to each other, connection must also have titles.

The biggest problem is that I need to get all the related values ​​without knowing exactly what are the connections and how many of them.

For example:

```
With VALUE 3 connected
VALUE 1 from the group A as NAME OF COMMUNICATION 1
and VALUE 2 from group B as NAME OF COMMUNICATION 2
and ...
```

Before any level of the connections (i.e., the values ​​of all properties connected to the associated properties, and for these properties and so on until a predetermined level) - but it can be implemented in the application logic.

I looked at some noSQL base, but they do not allow such requests without knowing the exact value or links. I pondered on the mysql development with a lot of logic in the application to handle all this, but perhaps there is a more suited storage for such a task?

I would be grateful for any help.

http://magika.tk/struct.png - A schematic example.

Comment: A mind-map is a graph, which means that a graph database like [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) would be an obvious solution.

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting and in many ways fits me!

Answer (score 1):

As Philipp says mind-maps are a type of graph, usually a spider diagram. A graph based NoSQL databases, such as Neo4j would be suitable. Here's a [longer list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#Graph_database_projects). Graph databases store information about the nodes and the edges. Each node has a pointer to all its adjacent nodes so counting connections and groups should be very fast.